# count data with shared row

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm facing with some data cleaning excercise and i have this type of data:

```
A<-c("A","A:::B","B")
B<-c("x","x","y")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B))
df
```

The example is:

```
      V1 V2
1     A  x
2 A:::B  x
3     B  y
```

I need this result:

```
     Var1Var2Count
1     A   x    2
2     B   x    1
3     B   y    1
```

I try some code like:

```
count<-aggregate(((unlist(strsplit(A,"\\:+"))))~B)
```

But i get error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ((unlist(strsplit(A, : variable lengths differ (found for 'B')
```

This because i thing after the unlist vector A became longer than before. How can I do?

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
> df %>% separate_rows(A, sep = ':::') %>% count(A,B, name = 'Count')
  A B Count
1 A x     2
2 B x     1
3 B y     1
>
```